# In Three.js Is there a way to produce a trail that slowly fades over time?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am looking to produce an effect very similar to the following example:
https://threejs.org/examples/?q=trails#webgl_trails

However, I would like to make the old trail fade into the background over time -- rather than just persist into an increasingly messy screen.

It seems that the following code will allow you to draw over previous frames without clearing them:

`renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { preserveDrawingBuffer: true } );
renderer.autoClearColor = false;`

But I am unsure how to make each frame fade into the background as new frames a drawn on top.  It seems like painting over the screen with a somewhat transparent color would work, but I'm not sure how to approach that.

Comment: try drawing an opaque rectangle over where you want to fade (just saw that you already said that)

Comment: Have you thought of using a [particle system](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_gpu_particle_system.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could easily take the example you showed above, and create a very faint black plane that sits directly in front of the camera:

```
// Make highly-transparent plane
var fadeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x000000,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.01
});
var fadePlane = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1, 1);
var fadeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(fadePlane, fadeMaterial);

// Create Object3D to hold camera and transparent plane
var camGroup = new THREE.Object3D();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
camGroup.add(camera);
camGroup.add(fadeMesh);

// Put plane in front of camera
fadeMesh.position.z = -0.1;

// Make plane render before particles
fadeMesh.renderOrder = -1;

// Add camGroup to scene
scene.add(camGroup);
```

This will make sure that every time the scene is rendered, it'll slowly fade the previously-rendered particles to black. You'll need to play with the opacity of `fadeMaterial` and position of `fadeMesh` to get the desired effect.

`renderOrder = -1;` makes sure that you render the plane first (fading out previous particles), and then render the particles, to avoid covering the newest ones.

Comment: Thanks!  that worked.  Since my camera also moves, I needed to make sure that `fadeMesh` continued to follow the camera around.  I ended up doing something like this for each axis:


```fadeMesh.position.x = camera.position.x+(camera.getWorldDirection().x*5);
 fadeMesh.rotation.x = camera.rotation.x;
```

Comment: @swirlybuns Oh, you shouldn't have to re-position `fadeMesh` separately from the camera. That's why I bundled it all into `camGroup` for you. If you only move `camGroup`, its children objects `camera` and `fadeMesh` will both move together.

Comment: @swirlybuns is there a way to do the same but preserving the entire transparency of the renderer / scene? I'd like to do the same BUT I have stuff under the canvas that needs to be visible. This approach works only it you have a plain color background :)

Comment: Can you expand on this answer please? I'm just starting to learng three.js and I have no idea how to implement this.

Comment: @IvanHid Sorry, I shouldn't make updates to an accepted answer to cover everyone's use case. Why don't you open a new question with the problem you're having and show your code so others can help with your specific situation?

Comment: @Marquizzo I'ts working now thanks a lot!, turns out I was requesting the animation frame before doing any logic or rendering the camera :S, if anyone in the future needs to do something similar I did a barebones example here: https://codepen.io/IvanHidalgo/pen/qBWMEwz

Answer (score 5):

There's now an example using the postprocessing EffectComposer and AfterImagePass.

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_afterimage.html

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that existed! The only downside of using EffectComposer is that you also lose native anti-aliasing in WebGL1.

Comment: I don't understand why setting the [WebGLRenderer](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.autoClear)'s `autoClear` property to false and/or running the `.setClearAlpha(0.0)` method doesn't produce results like this. There should be a way to control how the renderer clears frames. Maybe webgl doesn't work like opengl in this way...